# Unity Спавн объекта через корутину

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
void Update()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnBox(10));
    }
    IEnumerator SpawnBox(float time)
    {
        PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("AmmoBox", new Vector3(Random.Range(-3, 3), -.2f, Random.Range(-3, 3)), new Quaternion(0, Random.Range(-360, 360), 0, 0));
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(15);
    }
```

Почему оно спавнит очень много и не ждет ?
Я хочу добиться чтобы оно спавнило один объект и ждало 10 секунд, и так циклично
Как это сделать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все я нашел, так как оно в Update оно выполняется каждый кадр независимо.
Я все прописал в старт таким образом :

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(SpawnBox(17));
}
IEnumerator SpawnBox(float time)
{
    while (true)
    {
        PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("AmmoBox", new Vector3(Random.Range(-3, 3), -.2f, Random.Range(-3, 3)), new Quaternion(0, Random.Range(-360, 360), 0, 0));
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    }
}
```